# How does not | (Bitwise OR) work in SQL Server/SSIS 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I've read about the Bitwise OR and it seems to be like it functions same as OR except it's faster.

I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714(v=sql.110).aspx

And here is the example they give:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

SELECT a_int_value | b_int_value
FROM tableName
```

How is this expected to run? It makes no sense, you cannot have an OR in the select statement

1) Am I missing something? 
2) Is it safe to say that if my comparison expressions are of type integer, I should always use bitwise OR? (this is because bitwise OR is faster and works only on integer comparisons?)

Comment: wish I could vote up your answers but I am missing a couple of rep points :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a whole lot of experience with that flavor of SQL, but a bitwise OR  is not the same thing as an OR clause in the WHERE statement.

The bitwise OR will OR each bit of the integer together to produce a new integer
For example, the numbers 2 and 9 can be represented in binary as 0010 and 1001. 
So therefore

```
0010 | 1001 = 1011
```

In other words

```
2 | 9 = 11
```

The | operator in your statement is performing this operation on the results.

Please note that this operation is not equivalent to addition i.e.

```
5(0101) | 3(0011) = 7(0111)
```

Comment: Not sure if you meant to type &| or just &, and (0001) == 1, not 2. But yes, 5 bitwise AND 3 = 1

Comment: typo indeed. lol actually I got it wrong, but I do get the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`OR` is an infix logical operator.  It takes two Boolean expressions as arguments and returns TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN.  Boolean is a special type in SQL Server; it's only available indirectly.  You can't create a column or variable with the Boolean data type, for example.  It's used solely for logical processing internally by SQL Server, most often in the WHERE clause.

`|` is an infix bitwise operator.  It takes two integer, BIT, BINARY, or VARBINARY expressions (only one BINARY or VARBINARY is allowed) as arguments returns an integer result (or NULL).  Bitwise operations work on data expressions.

Take a look at the examples in the documentation for [bitwise OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714.aspx) and [`OR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually gave those links in my question and I did read them but didn't get them. But once reading the answers now I see where my mistake was. Thanks

Comment: wish I could vote up your answers but I am missing a couple of rep points :(